# DevExpress GridControl styles in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, devexpress, .net-standard

DevExpress GridControl have GridControl.View dependency property for customising grid, but in UWP haven`t exists its property. How customise GridControl in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start customizing the [DevExpress Grid for UWP](https://documentation.devexpress.com/Win10Apps/12040/Controls/Data-Grid) from reading the [Visual Elements](https://documentation.devexpress.com/Win10Apps/12031/Controls/Data-Grid/Visual-Elements) documentation article. Each topic in this article contains a list of the settings that you can touch to change the element's visibility, content and appearance.
Then you can start to customize the specific visual elements, for example like it demonstrated in the following example [How to: Display an Image within a Column Header](https://documentation.devexpress.com/Win10Apps/12166/Controls/Data-Grid/Examples/Styles-and-Templates/How-to-Display-an-Image-within-a-Column-Header)